# How to derive plain text from summernote text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, summernote

I am using summernote text editor in a rails app. When I type in plain text in the editor, I get html tags and other characters alongside the text i typed in the editor. I would like to know how i can derive just plain text in the output. I tried this solution i found online but I get an error saying 'var is a reserved word'

```
var plainText = $($("#summernote").summernote("code")).text()
```

This is the summernote code in my coffee file

```
$ ->
$('[data-provider="summernote"]').each ->
  $(this).summernote
    height: 300
```

Comment: the code you found, it's in javascript. Convert it to coffee

Comment: i converted it like this    plainText = $($('#summernote').summernote('code')).text()
but it did not solve the problem

Comment: it still complains about `var`?

Comment: you are missing  a semicolon in the javascript

Comment: @SergioTulentsev this is the conversion to coffee plainText = $($('#summernote').summernote('code')).text()
I used this online converter  http://js2.coffee/ . but it is still not working. It does not complain about 'var'

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio it does not work even with a semicolon

Comment: any help on the above question?  @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Must be the snippet you found somewhere is not working with the version you have. I assume that summernote editor has documentation, with usage examples? Have you tried reading that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a simple solution to this problem and it is without JavaScript. After typing or pasting text into the editor, you have to sanitize the output. So for example, in your show page, you do

```
      <%= sanitize @job.description %>
```

Then you derive your plain text without any hassle. 
`